# using MailChimp on LAN CiviCRM

Tags: civimail, email, mailing, mailchimp

Our institute uses CiviCRM only on our LAN. is it possible to use mailChimp for bulk emailing, CiviMail, in our LAN CiviCRM.?

Wordpress, Wamp 3, Windows 7

Answer (score 1):

If the machine that connects to mailchimp (the wamp machine) can reach the internet then yes.

Comment: Indeed, the machine connects to internet. But If I have to use CiviCRM groups in MailChimp, then I think I have to use Webhooks. But webhooks with localhost URL won't work. so I am stuck here.

Comment: Fair point. It's true that if you make changes to your lists at mailchimp they wouldn't sync back to your CiviCRM. But any changes you make in Civi will still sync to mailchimp.

Comment: is it so? ok. Let me see.