# Google forms, mailchimp and civicrm

Tags: forms, civicrm-home, mailchimp

I want to collect some data from our contacts through Google forms, which I can do.

But is there a possibility to link to civicrm through mailchimp? I am new to civicrm and mailchimp. What can be done and how to do it? I just want to know what all options I have, before I opt for a simple Google form.

I am using wordpress. And my CiviCRM works on LAN not integrated with any website.

Comment: do you want to clarify your CMS? Drupal sites can send out mail with checksums to take users to a Drupal webform using the webform_civicrm module so the data is collected directly in civicrm. Just wondering why you are opting for Google forms - or perhaps you don't want the data in civicrm?

Comment: I am using wordpress. And my CiviCRM works on LAN not integrated with any website. So I think, I will not be able to capture the data directly in CiviCRM. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 3):

There is a Mailchimp CiviCRM Integration Extension which you can download.
Details are here at https://civicrm.org/extensions/mailchimp-civicrm-integration

Details on how to enable extensions are at https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Extensions

Comment: Yeah. I did that.  I came across this extension . https://connect.mailchimp.com/integrations/google-docs  Will this help me in collecting data from google docs, imported to mailChimp and from mailChimp,can I import to CiviCRM. My CiviCRM is only on LAN of my institute and not connected to any website. Is there any similar other extension which does this job?

Comment: Sorry but I don't have any working knowledge of the extension I've suggested.  It would be best to contact the authors Deepak Srivastava, and Parvez Saleh at the link I've given.

Do you now wish to close down your other similar question at https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/19938/using-mailchimp-on-lan-civicrm?